SQL: Batch replacing integer values in a query with their textual values
I have several columns in table BASE that have values of 1, 2, and 3.
Instead of a query returning with these boolean/integer values, I'd like the query to return with No, Yes, and N/A, respectively.
I actually have another table CODE containing these values:



ID
Value




1
No


2
Yes


3
N/A



but I have around 20 columns in the BASE table so I don't want to use multiple JOIN statements to connect the ID column to the several columns in my BASE table. I think it would be the same with CASE statements.
OPTION 1. Multiple joins
SELECT c1.value,c2.value,c3.value,c4.value

FROM base b

JOIN CODE c1 ON c1.ID = b.col1
JOIN CODE c2 ON c2.ID = b.col2
JOIN CODE c3 ON c3.ID = b.col3
JOIN CODE c4 ON c4.ID = b.col4

I just used the CODE table for multiple JOIN statements for each of the columns in BASE but used a different alias each time.
OPTION 2. Multiple case statements
SELECT

CASE WHEN b.col1 = 1 THEN 'No'
WHEN b.col1 = 2 THEN 'Yes'
WHEN b.col1 = 3 THEN 'N/A'
ELSE NULL END as "col1_value",

CASE WHEN b.col2 = 1 THEN 'No'
WHEN b.col2 = 2 THEN 'Yes'
WHEN b.col2 = 3 THEN 'N/A'
ELSE NULL END as "col2_value",

CASE WHEN b.col3 = 1 THEN 'No'
WHEN b.col3 = 2 THEN 'Yes'
WHEN b.col3 = 3 THEN 'N/A'
ELSE NULL END as "col3_value",

CASE WHEN b.col4 = 1 THEN 'No'
WHEN b.col4 = 2 THEN 'Yes'
WHEN b.col4 = 3 THEN 'N/A'
ELSE NULL END as "col4_value",

FROM base b

I assume I also have to repeat the CASE statement for each column.
Both seem to be too long. If I have over 20 columns to work on, what would be the best way to do this?
Can I mass just replace these 1, 2, or 3 values with their respective textual equivalents? Like where I can declare these columns with the integer values and just mass replace their values?
I'm not trying to replace the actual values in the database, just the results from my SQL query.
Any suggestion would be great.

Make it easy to assist you, provide a complete [mcve]. (No need for 20 columns, perhaps 3 is enough?)

This is exactly why SQL uses normalised data structures. If you had 20 rows per ID, instead of 20 columns, you'd just need one join. So, the question becomes; are you able to normalise the table structure? If not, then unpivot/join/pivot is your only sensible option to avoid repeating code.

this query can fix your problem :
SELECT * FROM 
  (SELECT COL_NO , VALUE , ROUND((ROWNUM+1)/4) ROW_ID
   FROM base
   UNPIVOT (
    code_id 
    FOR col_no
    IN(
      col1, col2, col3, col4)
   ) t1
 JOIN code t2 
 ON t1.code_id = t2.id)
 PIVOT (
   MAX(value)
   FOR col_no 
   IN(
    'COL1' as col1,
    'COL2' as col2,
    'COL3' as col3,
    'COL4' as col4 )
  )

first, I unpivot your base table and join it to code table. then, I pivot joined table.
this query has been executed in oracle
T1 is like this:



COL_NO
CODE_ID
ROW_ID




col1
1
1


col2
2
1


col3
1
1


col4
3
1


col1
3
2



it is resulted by UNPIVOT the base table
so we join t1 and Code table. and replace Code_id column with Value of each code.



COL_NO
VALUE
ROW_ID




col1
NO
1


col2
Yes
1


col3
NO
1


col4
N/A
1


col1
N/A
2



then just pivot the result to convert this table to pivot table like base (but the value of each element is value of code instead of id)

Please format your code with indentations, and include commentary as to why this query unpivots, then joins, then pivots back again.

I edited the code with indentation.
t1 table  is unpivoted table. and it is like this:
col_no | value| row_id
COL1   |  YES   | 1

Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.

Please don't add this information in comments. Edit the answer.  (Also, if you read the link I gave, it has advice on how to add markdown tables to the answer text.)

I edited my answer. you can see the result

If it's just three fixed values you can use the CHOOSE function
SELECT
  CHOOSE(b.col1, 'No', 'Yes', 'N/A'),
  CHOOSE(b.col2, 'No', 'Yes', 'N/A'),
  CHOOSE(b.col3, 'No', 'Yes', 'N/A'),
  CHOOSE(b.col4, 'No', 'Yes', 'N/A')
FROM base b


I wouldn't recommend hardcoding the values in a dimension table unless performance is absolutely critical.
